# Binding the TextBlock of a Listview's GridView's DataGridCell

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I've got an `ObservableCollection` of model objects that I'm attempting to display in the `DataGridCells` of a `GridView` in a `ListView`. For this simplified example, let's say that my model objects all have "MyString," and that I'm attempting to show "MyString" in a `TextBlock` inside of each row's `DataGridCell`.

As the `ObservableCollection` adds or removes these model objects, the `ListView` shows the correct number of rows, however the individual cells are empty.  How do I properly bind them?  Should I be using `DataContext` or `ItemSource`, and if so, where?  Here's a single-column example of one such binding attempt.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="My String Data" />
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGridCell>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyString}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataGridCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

EDIT:  Per Michal Ciechan, I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my model class, but it didn't seem to change anything.  I won't actually be changing the fields on these objects once they're in the collection, however, so this may not be the right approach.  Here's some more example code.

The Model:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MyString;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

public void AddModelToCollection()
{
    MyModel mm = new MyModel();
    mm.MyString = "HELLO WORLD";
    MyObservableCollection.Add(mm);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a dummy model with INOtifyProeprty changed and view so I can test it in my end.

Comment: Maybe that's my problem!  I'm not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on my model class at this time. I'll try this and if it works, I'll let you know so you can get some answer credit here.

Comment: Haha, yes definitely. But that would only be the case if you are setting the MyString to something after adding it. Otherwise it should correctly pick it up first time.

Comment: No luck with INotifyPropertyChanged on the model class.  I've added more example code to show some of the relevant C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public string MyString;` is a field, not a property.  You can't bind to fields.  You can only bind to properties.

```
private string _myString;
public string MyString
{
    get
    {
        return _myString;
    }
    set
    {
        _myString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyString");
    }
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of `OnPropertyChanged` to you.

***To clarify***

This is a [PROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

```
public string DERP { get; set; }
```

Notice it has a getter and a setter.  The compiler turns this into two methods, one for getting the value and one for setting it.

This is a [FIELD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173118(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public string HERP;
```

Notice, it doesn't have a getter or a setter.  It is just a pointer to a value on the stack.

Here comes the important bit:

#### In WPF, Bindings do NOT WORK with **FIELDS**.  They only work with **PROPERTIES**

So setting the value of a field prior to attempting to bind against it matters not.  The Binding won't be looking for fields, and therefore won't see it.

Comment: Not quite sure what to do with this.  I instantiate `MyModel mm`, and then I set the value of `MyString` _before_ adding `mm` to `MyObservableCollection`.  I'm expecting the addition of these objects to the collection to be reflected in the UI, which is happening to some degree because I see a correct number of rows with blank cells.  I'm never reaching into this collection and changing `MyString` on an object that was previously added.

Comment: @Hoffma you've got to reading comprehension. I've clarified a bit about the distinction between fields and properties and the fact that bindings don't work with fields, period.  You can snag a runtime visual debugger like Snoop, browse to the binding, and see that it is invalid.

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go after all...?  I'll implement and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @Hoffma No, you can totally use fields.  Your application just won't work.

Comment: I'm good to go.  Thanks @Will!  You're right, regardless of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it was my failure to properly implement both fields and properties here that was causing the issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: kk @Hoffma make sure you snag Snoop.  It'll help you on your WPF journey!

Comment: Will do!  And thanks for updating your answer with that priceless clarification.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Will is right, your Model class needs to have `MyString` as a Property rather than field.

[What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

[WPF - Binding - Binding Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx)

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.
>   For more information about how to implement a class that can serve as a binding source, see Implementing a Class for the Binding Source later in this topic.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            return _myString;
        }
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyString");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'll be!  I'll have to test this and let you guys know how it goes.  :)  Thanks to the both of you!